# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502 on Minikube with Ingress

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, minikube

Trying to create a simple websocket server on minikube with ingress.
While connecting with the ws://192.168.99.119/ getting the below error.

**WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.99.119/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502**

Please help me to fix this issue. Below provided the details of the implementation.

> Websocket Server implementation

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as http from 'http';
import * as WebSocket from 'ws';

interface ExtWebSocket extends WebSocket {
    id: string; // your custom property
    isAlive: boolean
}
const PORT = parseInt(process.env.NODE_PORT) || 8010;

const app = express();

//initialize a simple http server
const server = http.createServer(app);

//initialize the WebSocket server instance
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', (ws: ExtWebSocket) => {

    //connection is up, let's add a simple simple event
    ws.on('message', (message: string) => {

        //log the received message and send it back to the client
        console.log('received: %s', message);

        const broadcastRegex = /^broadcast\:/;

        ws.isAlive = true;

        ws.on('pong', () => {
            ws.isAlive = true;
        });

        if (broadcastRegex.test(message)) {
            message = message.replace(broadcastRegex, '');

            //send back the message to the other clients
            wss.clients
                .forEach(client => {
                    if (client != ws) {
                        client.send(`Hello, broadcast message -> ${message}`);
                    }
                });

        } else {
            ws.send(`Hello, you sent -> ${message}`);
        }
    });

    //send immediatly a feedback to the incoming connection
    ws.send('Hi there, I am a WebSocket server');
});

setInterval(() => {
    wss.clients.forEach((ws: ExtWebSocket) => {

        if (!ws.isAlive) return ws.terminate();

        ws.isAlive = false;
        ws.ping(null, false);
    });
}, 10000);

//start our server
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${JSON.stringify(server.address())}`);
});
```

> Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install

COPY ./ /app/
RUN npm run build

CMD ["node","./dist/server.js"]

EXPOSE 8010
```

> Websocket service yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: socketserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: socketserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: socketserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: socketserver
        image: kireeti123/socketserver:1.0.2
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8010
          name: wsport
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: socketserver-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: socketserver
  ports:
  - port: 8010
    targetPort: 80
---
```

> Ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: socketserver-svc
    nginx.org/websocket-services: socketserver-svc
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: socketserver-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have `targetPort` set to `80` while your `Pod` exposes port `8010` ? It won't work.

Switch port numbers in your `Service` definition so it looks like in the example below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: socketserver-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: socketserver
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8010
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing the mistake I made. It worked like a charm now. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Hi @Mario, I have another question which is the next step to this question. Kindly let me know if you have a idea. Question is here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336969/error-on-websocket-implementation-on-azure-kubernetes-cluster-not-working